# Assignment operator for a structure

Tags: structure, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

I'm trying to assign some default values to a structure elements.
My structure is as follows:

```
struct SourceProperties
        {
            SoundTypes                                  m_SoundTypes;
            ChannelGroupType                            m_channelGroupType;
            SoundTrigger                                m_SoundTrigger;
            QE::CVector                                 m_SourcePosition;                               
            QE::CVector                                 m_SourceVelocity;                   
            QE::CVector                                 m_Up;                               
            QE::CVector                                 m_Forward;                      
            QE::CMatrix                                 m_SourceOrientation;                
            float                                       m_SourceIntensity;
            QE::CVector                                 m_SoundFactors;                             
        };
```

`CVector` and `CMatrix` are defined classes in our own engine and `SoundTypes`, `ChannelGroupType` and `SoundTrigger` are of "enum" type.
I need to define the default values of the element values in the constructure of another class. To be more clear, the user sets the values of the elements of this structure, using the instance of this structure in another class. Here is a pSeudo code:

The class where the structure is defined (header file):

```
class  CSound
    {
    public:

struct SourceProperties
        {
            SoundTypes                                  m_SoundTypes;
            ChannelGroupType                            m_channelGroupType;
            SoundTrigger                                m_SoundTrigger;
            QE::CVector                                 m_SourcePosition;                               
            QE::CVector                                 m_SourceVelocity;                   
            QE::CVector                                 m_Up;                               
            QE::CVector                                 m_Forward;                      
            QE::CMatrix                                 m_SourceOrientation;                
            float                                       m_SourceIntensity;
            QE::CVector                                 m_SoundFactors;                             
        };

private: 
      SourceProperties m_SourceProperties;
};

The class in which we assign the default values (header and cpp file):

class CSoundComponent :
{
 private:
  CSound::SourceProperties  m_SoundProperties;
}

The cpp file:

QE::CSoundComponent()
{
    m_SoundProperties.m_SoundTypes          = CSound::SoundTypes::ST_3D;
    m_SoundProperties.m_SoundTrigger       =CSound::SoundTrigger::STR_EVENT;
    m_SoundProperties.m_Forward             = CVector(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    m_SoundProperties.m_Up                  = CVector(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    m_SoundProperties.m_SourcePosition      = CVector(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    m_SoundProperties.m_channelGroupType=CFMODChannelGroup::ChannelGroupType::CGP_DEFAULT;
    m_SoundProperties.m_SourceIntensity     = 10000.0f;
    m_SoundProperties.m_SoundFactors        = CVector(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

oid QE::CSoundComponent::SetSoundProperties(QE::CSound::SourceProperties pSourceProperties)
{
    m_SoundProperties.m_SoundTypes          = pSourceProperties.m_SoundTypes;
    m_SoundProperties.m_channelGroupType    = pSourceProperties.m_channelGroupType;
    m_SoundProperties.m_SoundTrigger        = pSourceProperties.m_SoundTrigger;
    m_SoundProperties.m_SourcePosition      = pSourceProperties.m_SourcePosition;
    m_SoundProperties.m_SourceIntensity     = pSourceProperties.m_SourceIntensity;
    m_SoundProperties.m_SoundFactors        = pSourceProperties.m_SoundFactors; 
}



}

The class which user is utilizing(cpp):

class userclass
{

CSound::SourceProperties lSoundProperties;
lSoundProperties.m_SoundTypes = CSound::SoundTypes::ST_3D;
QE::CSoundComponent* lSoundComponent;
lSoundComponent->setSoundProperties(lSoundProperties);
}
```

for some reason all the values that the user is assigining is are set properly, all the default values are also set except for the float value.
Does anyone have any idea how I should define the assignment operator "="? Thank you.